# Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Magento 2

Tags: magento2

After installation of Fresh Magento 2.3 on my sub-domain i got this error.

> {"0":"Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(var/www/html/var/session/sess_nloiac096cn9o6imqdkouoj96l, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/www\$

i have followed some of tutorials but they did not worked.

Comment: did you set 777 permission to var directory

Comment: did you restart apache server

Comment: do you have session folder available on this path?

Comment: i dont know, what if just write files instead of thsi dir?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [Magento 2.3 Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_session.html)  
This happens when your session.save_handler PHP parameter is set to some another session storage than files (for example, redis, memcached, and so on).

To solve it follow Magento suggestions :

**1 - [Upgrade Magento 2 Code](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall.html#instgde-install-magento-update)**

**2 - Locate php.ini**

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

As a user with root privileges, open php.ini in a text editor.
Locate session.save_handler
Set it in any of the following ways:

To comment it out:

```
;session.save_path = <path>
```

To set it to a file system path:

```
session.save_handler = files
```

**3. Open app/etc/env.php**

Change:

```
'session' =>
  array (
    'save' => 'files'
  ),
```

to

```
'session' =>
  array (
    'save' => 'db'
  ),
```

Comment: is this oky now? http://prntscr.com/nttvef

Comment: yes i think it is fine , or you can better just modifie to this :  session.save_handler = files , but see if it works when you comment it .

Comment: it is not working there are many ;session.save_path  available, which one i have to change?

Comment: Look for the one that it isnt commented , in your case i guess it is this https://cl.ly/9227a11ce928 , then after the modification restart apache server : /etc/init.d/httpd restart

Comment: i did same as in screenshot but its same http://prntscr.com/ntubxi

Comment: Add this : session.save_handler = files (as a root user) and restart apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94148/discussion-between-i-ali55-and-ylgen-guxholli).

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli After update with your suggestion make sure there is no error in upgrade?

Comment: Why enabling session save_handler as files then setting magento session as db?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes js are not loaded because of missing .htaccess in var/pub/static folder. Just check .htaccess file exists or not in hidden files also.

Answer (score 1):

Locate php.ini by entering the following command:

> php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"

Typical locations follow:

- Ubuntu: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
- CentOS: /etc/php.ini

Open php.ini with root user, and comment it out:

> ;session.save_path =

to

> session.save_path = files

Comment: is this okay? http://prntscr.com/nttwcp

Comment: did you restart apache server

Comment: yes, i did, actully the problem was, i was saving my sessions in files, your answer is fine if someone wants to save sessions in files.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution for this is to set your 'var' or 'var/sessions' or 'var/sessions' ownership to the web user because Session path can't be written to since the web user and the owner of the content in the sessions folder are different and thus doesn't .

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/sessions

Answer (score 0):

Restart Nginx or Apache web services

by executing these commands for RHET:
systemctl restart httpd
/scripts/restartsrv_apache_php_fpm