# Magento 2.3 - Unexpected error Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::read()

Tags: magento2.3, error, nginx, centos, exception-error

I am getting Unexpected error,

**Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/opt/remi/php72/lib/php/session/sess_5292j25aa4ugpdgrv9r6a3l3p8, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /usr/share/nginx/html/gta/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22 in /usr/share/nginx/html/gta/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61**

How to solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

For me I have solved this problem by deleting the session that is causing the problem (it is indicated in the message Exception: Warning).
Identify this problematic php session in the php session directory,
**with this command**:
sudo ls -la var/lib/php/sessions/
For me it's: **sess_6uha84kjcvjmq6qjsh0ctee5ff**,
then simply delete it, being careful to run the rm command with sudo:
sudo rm -rf var/lib/php/sessions/**sess_6uha84kjcvjmq6qjsh0ctee5ff**
my site reloaded without problem.
I hope this will help you.
Made in magento 2.4.2

Comment: Worked for a Magento 2.3.2 as well, Thanks!

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seems to be Magento related, but PHP related.

The error says `Permission denied`, so the user executing the PHP code can't write on the PHP session path.

As you mention nginx, I assume you're using php-fpm. Check your pool to see the `user` and `group` and verify if it matches the rights on the path
 `/var/opt/remi/php72/lib/php/session`

Sometimes it also happens when nginx is using the `nginx` user and not `www-data` user.

Comment: I just followed this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/276210/57334 solved.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have this issue when circling from one version to another for the same instance. I noticed that deleting that session from `/var/lib/sessions/` solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Open `www.config` file of `php-fpm` and locate the configs session.save_handler, session.save_path, and make the below changes:

`php_value[session.save_handler] = files`

`;php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/session`

if this does not work, then make the same changes in the `php.ini` file of your system. For Centos, it is located at `/etc/php.ini`.